# `-e` as an iteration item in bash's for loop

Tags: bash

I have the following bash code:

```bash
$ for x in -c -d -e -f ; do echo $x ; done
-c
-d

-f
```

Anyone has any idea why `-e` didn't show up?

I'm using bash 5.1.4.

Comment: Ask yourself: What does `echo -e` do? (It's actually a [much trickier question than you'd think](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo))

Comment: (if you `set -o posix` and `shopt -s xpg_echo`, _then_ `echo -e` will write `-e` on output).

Comment: ...but realistically, _don't use `echo`_. `printf '%s\n' -e` does The Right Thing.

Comment: Oh! I got it. Thanks! I was just assuming it's the for loop doing weird stuff.

Comment: Using `set -x` to enable trace logging is always a good place to start. (Also, get in the habit of using `echo "$x"` instead of `echo $x`; it won't save you from this bug, but [it will save you from other ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else))

Comment: Also see [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/264812).

Comment: See _man bash_, the section titled _SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS_. It explains the `echo` command and shows why your approach does not work. A `-n` wouldn't have worked either for the same reason.